# Access CRM web services externally

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm

Could someone please tell me how to access CRM (IFD) webservices from outside the domain?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll have to set up the instance for IFD support.  Microsoft has an IFD setup tool.

You'll then want to make sure your website is exposed to the internet.  It sounds like you can successfully ping it from the above comments.

You can then use the web services if you provide the appropriate url and network credentials.

```
service.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username",
                "pass@word1", "domain");
```

Answer (score 0):

A VPN setup is often a good way to accomplish this. That will involve opening the appropriate ports in your (or your company's) firewall, as well.

Answer (score 0):

thats exactly what i did and i found out that theres nothing wrong with the way i access the web services but sommeone has turned off basic authentication of the CRM application, turned it back on and problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

actually if you right click on the website(from iis) and go into the security section, it lets you select the authentication type , eg: anonymous, basic or windows. you should not require to turn off the authentication in CRM, as i found out you need to have basic authentication enabled in order to access remotely.

regards,
lasa